# the POST request is changed to GET in my docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, post, docker-compose, axios

I created site copy via docker-compose.

The problem is when send post request in my Vue component via axios:

```
axios.post('/ajax/form/product-question/?token=' + this.token, {
  NAME: this.Dname,
  EMAIL: this.Demail,
  PHONE: this.Dphone,
  MESSAGE: this.message,
}).then(response => {
  this.visibility = false;
}
```

i get an error:
[image: bad request]

The error description from Response:

```
error
: 
"No route found for \"GET http://dev.site.loc/ajax/form/product-question/\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)"
```

This request processed by Symfony function which worked with POST (not GET)

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

networks: 
    internal:
services:
  php:
    build: ./build/php
    image: php:7.4-apache
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./dev_site_com/public:/var/www/html
      - ./dev_site_com/vendor:/var/www/vendor
      - ./dev_site_com/assets:/var/www/assets
      - ./dev_site_com/src:/var/www/src
      - ./dev_site_com/.env:/var/www/.env
      - ./dev_site_com/public:/var/www/public
      - ./dev_site_com/package.json:/var/www/package.json
      - ./dev_site_com/webpack.mix.js:/var/www/webpack.mix.js
      - ./build/php-ini/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
    extra_hosts:
      - "dev.site.loc:127.0.0.1"
    hostname: dev.site.loc
    domainname: site.loc
    ports:
      - 80:80  
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=dev_site"
    networks:
      - internal
  mysql:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    build: './build/mysql'
    container_name: dev_site
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "super-secret-password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "dev_site"
    volumes:
      - dbData:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=dev_site
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    networks:
      - internal
volumes:
  app:
  dbData:
```

And my question is: what's wrong in my docker-compose? Or maybe something else..

Thanks for your advices

> 

I was checking functions from prod site. It's like my axios function.
They give the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but maybe the answer will be helpful for others.
If you use SSL certificates on your docker make sure you always use URLs with https://.
Otherwise the server will answer with a redirect (301) firstly, for which the client will follow using GET instead of original method (POST/PUT). This depends on the client, for me it happened using guzzle.

Answer (score 0):

another solution: i'm recreated site copy via laradock.
Some edits nginx conf and thats all. It's worked!

But my docker-compose bug is still interesting...